# Interpretation of return address stack in risc v architecture

Tags: riscv

As it is stated in page 16 of riscv-specv-v2.2.pdf, return-address prediction stacks are used.

It states that for JAL will should push the return address onto the return-address stack when rd = x1/x5.

But does it mean to

1. push the old return address onto then stack, i.e. return address before the JAL instruction, the value of x1 before executing JAL
2. push the new return address, i.e. the address of the next instruction after JAL?

Thank you.

Comment: What would be the point of pushing the old value in `x1`/`x5` onto the predictor stack? The old value is not a return address. But I guess you could push it if you wanted to. The return address predictor is not part of the ISA, so each implementation is free to manage it however it wants, including pushing garbage onto it if it wants to.

Comment: my answer was wrong I deleted it. I post a similar question on riscv-isa mailing list - the answers are very interesting : https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/164936ff05e44267

Comment: Fixed link: https://groups.google.com/a/groups.riscv.org/d/topic/isa-dev/lto2XZlEH0k/discussion